# Flutter Dartz bloc test argument type not assignable issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, bloc, bloc-test

I am writing flutter test method using bloc_test and mockito library. I am getting below strange issue while mocking repository API call. It might be a simple fix but I am trying it since last couple of hours :(.

[image]

Similar code is present in other public repositories but here its not working.

```
when(() => mockRepository.getPosts())
              .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(postEntityList));
```

getPosts method structure :

```
  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, List<PostEntity>>> getPosts() async {
  }
```

Basic blocTest method code:

```
group('whenListen', () {
    blocTest('verify posts bloc tests',
        build: () {
          when(() => mockRepository.getPosts())
              .thenAnswer((_) async => postEntityList);
          return postsBloc;
        },
        act: (PostsBloc postBloc) {
          postBloc.getAllPostsUseCase();
        },
        expect: () => (isA<PostsInitial>()));
  });
```

Comment: I prefer fpdart over dartz.  I wouldn't expect you to change, but this message is for people reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using it in the right way. `dartz` package uses `Right` or `Left` classes to access the actual type.
Simply change the `postEntityList` to `Right(postEntityList)`

```dart
when(() => mockRepository.getPosts())
              .thenAnswer((_) async => Right(postEntityList));
```

Comment: I tried it also .In fact I was using it the first time. but still its giving same error.  Will update my question

Comment: What's the type of `postEntityList`?

Comment: final postEntity = PostEntity(id: 1, title: "test", body: "body desc");
  List<PostEntity> postEntityList = [postEntity];